# Recursive function in PHP return fatal error

Tags: php, recursion

I am trying to create function in PHP for looking for users like @Sometihng in string and then put link to their profiles into the string, but whenn I use it, it return **Fatal error: Cannot redeclare userTags()**. Do you know where is problem or what am I doing wrong? Here is my code. Thanks for any help.

```
$comment = "Hey @Name how are you?? And how is @AnotherName. Also have you seen @SomeName ??";

function userTags($startFrom) {

    $pos = strpos($comment, '@', $startFrom);     

    if ($pos !== false) {  

        $pos1 = strpos($comment, ' ', $pos);

        if ($pos1 !== false) {

            $insert_string = '<a href="profile.php?owner=somewhere">';
            $insert_string1 = "</a>";

            $comment = substr_replace($comment, $insert_string1, $pos1, 0);
            $comment = substr_replace($comment, $insert_string, $pos, 0);  

            userTags($pos1); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears that you are attempting to redeclare the userTags function. Maybe you are including the same file twice? Try require_once or include_once instead of require/include

Comment: The error message says it: you defined the function `userTags()` twice and this is not allowed. Maybe you defined it only once in a file that is included more than once in the same script? (Maybe through indirect inclusions?)

Comment: The problem isn't in the code you posted.

Comment: Can you show how you are calling it? You aren't accidentally using the `function` keyword again when you call it, are you?

Comment: You could do this pretty easily with `preg_replace`. `@(\w+?)\b`. (depending on what valid characters are for a username)

Comment: Thanks all. Yes I had that function in while loop so it was declared more than once. Can you write it as an answer so I can approve it for you?

Comment: I'd use sprintf instead. Much simpler and quicker! @MatusMihely nobody realised it was in a loop. You essentially answered it yourself, and it's encouraged that you create your own answer in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try regex instead. :) `'/(?<!\w)@\S+/'` will extract all words starting with @character.

```
$comment = "Hey @Name how are you?? And how is @AnotherName. Also have you seen @SomeName ??";

preg_match_all('/(?<!\w)@\S+/', $comment, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: Is it poossible with it add in front of every extracted word <a> tag and behind it </a> tag and put it back into the comment string with it?

Comment: Well this: `$updated_comment = preg_replace('/(@(\w+))/', '<a>\1</a>', $comment);` will return: `Hey <a>@Name</a> how are you?? And how is <a>@AnotherName</a>. Also have you seen <a>@SomeName</a> ??` Then you can just use php function `str_replace()`. I might find pure regex solution but that would take me a lot longer.

Comment: Also you will probably want specific href for link for every variable in sentence so it is better just to use `str_replace("<a>@name</a>", "<a href='your/href'>$name</a>", $updated_comment)`. Just use for loop on `$updated_comment` for every variable that you find in `$comment`. :)

Comment: Also someone in comments suggested using `sprintf()` that is probably much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Function was located in the while loop so it was declared more than once.